# Is there a way to use a GNU-Screen in a portable-like way?

Tags: server, permissions, gnu-screen, hosting

I have website on shared hosting, and I haven't (and never had) permission to install software here. Just full access to my `/home/<username>/` folder.

But before the hoster moved my sites to the new server (old was with FreeBSD) I was able to download and build the Screen, place the binary in my `/home/<username>/bin`, add this directory to the PATH variable, and then use the Screen as usual.

But now, after all is moved to the new server (with Ubuntu), I cant find a way to do the trick again.

I've tried to copy the Screen binary, installed on my Amazon AWS-server, but it caused error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libutempter.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to copy this library, because I thought, that these Unix versions could be compatible, at least `uname` gives `Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` in both cases... but nothing changed...

I've tried to place it in `/home/<username>/bin`, `/home/<username>/share`, `/home/<username>/lib64` (because on AWS server it was found in `/usr/lib64`), but nothing changed at all, I still have this error...

So the question is - How to run the Screen (and other software, in general) in portable-like way, skipping full-installation (but just placing pre-built binaries to my local folders instead), with my limited permissions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't have permission from the system owner or admin to install software on their system...then it's probably not a good idea to seek a workaround so you can do exactly that.

Comment: actually, support engineer answered me that I'm free to use any side softwear if it will work fine in terms of existing permission, so that's legal :)

Comment: Well, you were honest with them - that's great!

Answer (score 0):

Compiling statically has worked well for me so far:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-static" && make
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947695/build-screen-with-ldflags-static) for a bit more info - I had good results just ignoring the warning it gives about getpwnam - at least so far.

The answer at that link references something about static builds being *less* portable, but that doesn't make sense to me given my experience and [info on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_build).